# Subjunctive or indicative after “je trouve que”?

Tags: grammaire, subjonctif, subordonnées, indicatif

> Je trouve que Max a du talent.
>
> Je trouve **normal** qu'il **ait** du succès.

Why is the **subjonctif** used in the second sentence?

Answer (score 8):

The parallel between the two sentences doesn't hold. In the first one, you give your opinion about Max's gift.  If you remove "trouver" and you just state a fact, you'll say

> Max a du talent.

In the second sentence, you give your opinion about the naturalness of Max success and not about the existence itself of the success. State a fact again, you'll say

> Il est normal qu'il ait du succès.
>   Qu'il ait du succès est normal.

But the use of the subjontif is quite complex and often a question of usage more than rational rules. See

> Qu'il ait du succès est certain.
>   Il est certain qu'il a du succès.

Answer (score -1):

Je trouve que + indicatif.

Je trouve **__** (adj) que + subjonctif.

(expression figée)

Comment: Is this answer true or not?